# Magento 2: Admin Move Filters & Paging to Top

Tags: magento2, admin, filter, design, pagination

I have below image in Admin. Don't know how it happened. But it moved to Bottom.

I have so many pages where it moved to Bottom.

How to move it to top position again.

[image]

Comment: did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes already done

Answer (score 0):

Please define dependencies in your module so that your module will load after the dependent module.

Add this code into your module.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales" />
    </sequence>
</config>
```

Refresh cache after this.

Answer (score 0):

Just in your xml file add below code inside the listing tag

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top"> 
.....
</listingToolbar>
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be due to orders of `ui_component` tag in modules `ui_component` xml file:-

[image]

Its just because of declarations of tag **listingToolbar** under the columns Tag in ui_component xml file.

[image]

Move this Tag listingToolbar above the columns then your filters will move up. Actually it render ui components in the same order as mentioned in the ui_component file. After moving up filters will render before the columns:

[image]

Comment: why down vote? its 100% correct answer and reason for that.